# Docker build после сборки образа создает дочерние образы

Tags: docker

Docker build после сборки образа создает дочерние образы `<none>`, которые не удалить
Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk add --no-cache nginx
RUN mkdir /run/nginx

COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Собираю образ:

```
docker build -t alpine_nginx .
```

или

```
docker build --rm -t alpine_nginx .
```

или

```
docker build --force-rm -t alpine_nginx .
```

Список образов:

```
anton@UbuntuDesktop:~/Projects/Docker/App$ docker image ls -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
alpine_nginx        latest              aba2846ed9a8        29 seconds ago      5.58MB
<none>              <none>              f66743a5c4c9        30 seconds ago      5.58MB
<none>              <none>              a7e63c600fcc        34 seconds ago      5.58MB
alpine              3.7                 9bea9e12e381        3 weeks ago         4.21MB
```

Пробовал `docker image prune -f` - ничего не удаляет

Так же `docker images -q -f dangling=true` - пусто, наверное фильтр устаревший

```
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
```

Comment: нужно удалить контейнеры `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` , и после удалить ненужные (в данном вашем случае) контейнеры `docker rmi $(docker images | grep '^<none>' | awk '{print $3}')`

Comment: Вы пропустили `-a` после `images`. Контейнеров не было, попробовал удалить:
`Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 1d086a3b93d4 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images`

Comment: попробуйте удалить все images. стереть абсолютно все. 
докер говорит, что есть зависимость, поэтому не удалит.

Comment: Он удаляет образы нормально, даже просто родительский удаляю и он удаляет дочерние нормально. Но просто дочерние образы не хочет. Может из-за обновления такого (вчера обновился, позавчера нормально было).
Такое ощущение, что докер создает на каждый слой новый образ, например, если я не буду копировать в образ конфиг nginx'а, то на 1 дочерний образ меньше будет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50126741/4827341

Answer (score -1):

```
docker images -q -f dangling=true | xargs -I ARGS docker rmi -f ARGS
```

Comment: 1. вы невнимательно прочитали вопрос: *Так же `docker images -q -f dangling=true` - пусто*. 2. `-l имя` в данном случае совершенно излишне.